# Korrektes Idiom: Neuer Wein in alten Schläuchen|Flaschen

Tags: idiom

Die Redewendung "Neuer Wein in alten Schläuchen" war für mich bisher immer gebräuchlich. Bei der [Übersetzung ins Englische](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Neuer%20Wein%20in%20alten) ist mir aufgefallen, dass es im Deutschen wohl auch die Redewendung "Neuer Wein in alten Flaschen" gibt.

Welche der beiden Redewendungen ist korrekt bzw. gebräuchlicher? Gibt es regionale Unterschiede?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im Duden, Band 11 *Redewendungen* (3. Auflage 2008) findet man nur

> junger Wein in alten Schläuchen

sowie

> neuer Wein in alten Schläuchen

Diese Wendung geht übrigens auf die Bibel (Matthäus 9,17) zurück:

> Auch füllt man nicht neuen Wein in alte Schläuche. Sonst reißen die Schläuche, der Wein läuft aus und die Schläuche sind unbrauchbar. Neuen Wein füllt man in neue Schläuche, dann bleibt beides erhalten.